# Dataframe python where conditions considering previous rows condition

Tags: python, dataframe

:)

I've a dataframe like that (it's an extract of the entire dataframe):

```
a   b
1   1   
6   3
7   5   
1   7
12  5
12  5   
2   5
95  2   
44  3
```

i want to create a new column using NumPy in python based on a multiple where conditions, considering previous conditions. Let me explain with an example:

I want to create column 'C' with value = '1' when:

```
(a > b) and (a[-1] < b) and (the previous valued value of "c" must be 2)
```

another condition is 'C' = '2' when:

```
(a < b) and (the previous valued value of "c" must be 1)
```

Thanks you!

Comment: You will have to iterate through the rows since one of your conditions depends on the 'C' column. I can't think of any way to exploit NumPy's inherent vectorization. Also, your conditions need an initial element to be correct, what is the first value of 'C'?

Comment: I think you are looking for  [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method in pandas. You can use this method on [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) or [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html). It will allow you to create condition like "previous value is 2".

Comment: Your two conditions are contradicting each other for first condition to be true the previous value of column `c` must be `2` while for second condition to be true the previous value of column `c` must be 1. You must have to create column `c` with some initial value?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the initial value. the initial value must be "1" when the first condition is met. I can't use shift function because I can't know exactly how many positions I have to move back. @Shubham Sharma

Comment: Can you share another sample of your dataframe because in the shared sample none of the above condition are satisfying also it would be better if you could share a dataframe with the expected output?

Comment: sorry, I wrote first condition wrong: (a > b) and (a[-1] < b) and (the previous valued value of "c" must be 2 OR NOTHING)

Comment: You need the `shift` function (this introduces a lead or lag in a column) as suggested above, and you will likely also need an intermediate column (e.g. `_a_b`) to apply the first two criteria and then create column `c` with a separate pass.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4mShKUSv @ShubhamSharma

Comment: @ DamianoDotto your output is still contradicting with your conditions, please check your output.

Comment: you're right! this is the correct example: https://pastebin.com/U2gmmGjc @ShubhamSharma Thanks you! :)

Comment: df['c']=(df['a']>df['b']) & (df['a'].shift(1) < df['b']) this is the first part of the first condition @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to return an array drawn from elements in choicelist, depending on conditions.
Use:

```
df['c'] = '' # --> assign initial value
conditions = [
    (df['a'].gt(df['b']) & df['a'].shift().lt(df['b'])) & (df['c'].shift().eq('') | df['c'].shift().eq(2)),
    df['a'].lt(df['b']) & (df['c'].shift().eq(1) | df['c'].shift().eq(''))
]

choices = [1, 2]
df['c'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='')
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
    a  b  c
0   1  1   
1   6  3  1
2   7  5   
3   1  7  2
4  12  5  1
5  12  5   
6   2  5  2
7  95  2   
8  44  3
```

Comment: Thanks you! It's work! :) I copy the entire code if someone need: https://pastebin.com/BEH4ykYk

Comment: Done! :) Thanks a lot Shubham Sharma!